# Dynamically created PHP button calls php function with AJAX onclick - not working

Tags: php, ajax, variables, button, onclick

I am currently building a psudo dataframe for testing an update contact function.  The onclick function is called, as I have used a window.alert to indicate that it reaches this part of the code. However, the AJAX call does not seem to instantiate itself at all.

Any assistance on this would be helpful - I am completely new to AJAX.

**The Code:**

Dynamically created button:

```
<td><Button class="Save" name="'.$contact["SCIContactID"].'" Value="Save" id="Save'.$count.'" Disabled="true" onclick="saveContact(this.name, \''.$contact["FirstName"].'\',\''.$contact["LastName"].'\',\''.$contact["Email"].'\',\''.$contact["Phone"].'\',\''.$contact["Comment"].'\')";></td></tr>';
```

Function of the onclick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveContact(ID, First, Last, Email, Phone, Comment)
{
$.AJAX({
  URL: "updateContact.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {"Update": ID, "ContactID": ID,  "FirstName": First, "LastName": Last, "Email": Email, "Phone": Phone, "Comment": Comment},
  success: windows.alert("Record updated"),
  error: window.alert("Error")      
});
}
</script>
```

Now, if I put:

```
window.alert(ID, First, Last, Email, Phone, Comment);
```

Above the Ajax call, all of the correct fields are being passed. First is the first name from the textbox, Last is the last name and whatnot

Within the updateContact.php is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['Update']))
{
updateContact($_POST['ContactID'], $_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['LastName'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST['Phone'], $_POST['Comment']); 
}
function updateContact($ContactID, $First, $Last, $Email, $Phone, $Comment)
{   
$con=database::getInstance()->getConnection();
$Update = $con->prepare('UPDATE SCIContact SET FirstName = :First, LastName = :Last, Email = :Email, Phone = :Phone, Comment = :Comment ');
$Update->bindValue(':First',$First, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Update->bindValue(':Last',$Last, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Update->bindValue(':Email',$Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Update->bindValue(':Phone',$Phones, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Update->bindValue(':Comment',$Comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Update->execute();
$con = null;
$Update =  null;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Realizes I was sending static variables... Changed button to:

```
<td><Button class="Save" name="'.$contact["SCIContactID"].'" Value="'.$count.'" id="Save'.$count.'" Disabled="true" onclick="saveContact(this.name, this.value)";></td></tr>';
```

and javascript function to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveContact(ID, Row)
{
String First = document.getElementById('FirstName'+Row).value;
String Last = document.getElementById('LastName'+Row).value;
String Email = document.getElementById('Email'+Row).value;
String Phone = document.getElementById('Phone'+Row).value;
String Comment = document.getElementById('Comment'+Row).value;

$.AJAX({
  URL: "updateContact.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {"Update": ID, "ContactID": ID,  "FirstName": First, "LastName": Last, "Email": Email, "Phone": Phone, "Comment": Comment},
  success: windows.alert("Record updated"),
  error: window.alert("Error")      
 });

 }
 </script>
```

**2nd Edit:**

Additionally: The fields provided in the table are given names based on their row #. So, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone and Comment of row 0 would be FirstName0, LastName0, Email0, Phone0, Comment0 and row 1 would be FirstName1, LastName1, Email1, Phone1, Comment1 and this would go on for all rows returned from the database.

**4th Edit:**

Forgot to import jquery. Added:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Modified function to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveContact(ID, Row)
{
var First = "" + document.getElementById('FirstName'+Row).value;
var Last = "" + document.getElementById('LastName'+Row).value;
var Email = "" + document.getElementById('Email'+Row).value;
var Phone = "" + document.getElementById('Phone'+Row).value;
var Comment = "" + document.getElementById('Comment'+Row).value;

if(First =="")
{
    document.getElementById('FirstName'+Row).value = "First Name Required";
    return;
}
else if(Last =="")
{
    document.getElementById('LastName'+Row).value = "Last Name Required";
  return;
} 
else 
{ 
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
   {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
  else 
  {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "updateContact.php?ID=" +ID +"&First="+ First + "&Las  t="+Last + "&Email="+Email + "&Phone="+Phone + "&Comment="+Comment, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}     
document.getElementById('FirstName'+Row).disabled=true;
document.getElementById('LastName'+Row).disabled=true;
document.getElementById('Email'+Row).disabled=true;
document.getElementById('Phone'+Row).disabled=true;
document.getElementById('Comment'+Row).disabled=true;
document.getElementById('Save'+Row).disabled=true;

}
</script>
```

Modified updateContact.php:

```
$ID = $_REQUEST["ID"];
$First = $_REQUEST["First"];    
$Last = $_REQUEST["Last"];
$Email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
$Phone = $_REQUEST["Phone"];
$Comment = $_REQUEST["Comment"];
$Success = true;
$Error = '';
if($Phone == "")
{
    $Phone = null;
}
if($Email == "")
{
    $Email=null;
}
updateContact($ID, $First, $Last, $Email, $Phone, $Comment);
```

This allows the save function to save the file to the database based on the row that was selected to be edited and then disables the fields. Rather than use the POST method, I went with the GET method, it seems to be working well.  Now all I need to do is to perform validation and return an error message or completion message.

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible with this code. Any help will be appreciated. If/When I find and answer, I will update this block with the final copy.

Comment: Why continue to use inline JS, especially when it is easy to target selectors, especially since you're using jQuery. It looks like you might have an event delegation problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If this is a security concern: In the future, this (The GUI) will be taken care of by another program. I'm building this as a proof of concept so that some people can see the data being manipulated (crudely) Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: `onclick="saveContact(this.name, this.value)";` is the inline JS, embedded in the HTML. It also looks like you're using duplicate ID's (FirstName, LastName, etc). ID's *must* be unique.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Just read up on it - Yeah. I use that because the 'table' is being dynamically created from the database. Thereby the name and the id of the save button are associated to the ID of the Contact to be changed and the Row of the table that is being edited. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way, but you need to get rid of the duplicate ID's first.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There are no duplicate ids. As the table is created, every FirstName and LastName created (h)as a number added to the end of the name. Thereby, row 0 would be FirstName0, LastName0, Email0, Phone0 and Comment0. Row 1 would be FirstName1, LastName1, Email1, Phone1, Comment1, etc. I've even ensured the save buttons are associated with Save0, Save1, Save 2, etc. I assure you, no duplication is present. Should I edit the code to show how the entire table is created to indicate this?

Comment: Ah - good. That was not evident here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So, if the IDs are all unique, what would be the better way to do this?

Comment: Use a class or use the HTML element as the selector. At this point we've entered fairly broad territory.